# Typedef struct unknown type name

Tags: c, struct, header, typedef

After searching for a while. I code a simple program to try and solve my bigger problem easier having little or no success. This is the code which works fine in main:

```
typedef struct nimaginario{
    int parte_real;
    int parte_imaginaria;
}nimaginario;

int suma(nimaginario *n){
    return n->parte_real + n->parte_imaginaria;
};

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    nimaginario *num = malloc(sizeof(nimaginario));
    num->parte_real = 1;
    num->parte_imaginaria = 2;
    int a = suma(num);
}
```

Then I try dividing it into the different parts it should be organized in. As to say: prueba.c, prueba.h, and main.c

prueba.h:

```
#define PRUEBA_H
#ifndef PRUEBA_H

typedef struct nimaginario{
    int parte_real;
    int parte_imaginaria;
}nimaginario;

int suma(nimaginario *n);

#endif
```

prueba.c:

```
#include "prueba.h"

int suma(nimaginario *n){
    return n->parte_real + n->parte_imaginaria;
};
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prueba.h"

int main(){

    nimaginario *num = malloc(sizeof(nimaginario));
    num->parte_real = 1;
    num->parte_imaginaria = 2;
    int a = suma(num);
}
```

In the first place I compiled with the command 'gcc main.c'
In second place I did as follows: 'gcc prueba.c main.c'

and for this second time and this specific try (out of one hundred) I get this errors:

```
prueba.c:3:10: error: unknown type name `nimaginario'
main.c: In function `main':
main.c:18:2: error: unknown type name `nimaginario'
main.c:18:35: error: `nimaginario' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:18:35: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:19:5: error: request for member `parte_real' in something not a structure or union
main.c:20:5: error: request for member `parte_imaginaria' in something not a structure or union
```

I think I have tried everything and anything. And seen all the errors I could see. I've also googled around a lot, and searched here in Stackoverflow with no success what so ever.

Things I've tried:

- Changing the typedef structure... and doing it step by step.

  - doing first typedef, then struct and vice versa.
- Changing the names of labels in struct and typedef.
- Checking #define /#ifndef
- Changing pointers all over (originally I wanted the struct to be to integer pointers) forgetting about typedef and working only with struct. Therefore declaring always as struct nimaginario.
- Checked where my files are.

I just fail to have a hammer close. I feel so numb It has just been a year without C...

Comment: `#define PRUEBA_H
#ifndef PRUEBA_H` should be `#ifndef PRUEBA_H #define PRUEBA_H`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an issue with the [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) ;-)

You want to *check* first then *define* it, not the other way around.

```
#define PRUEBA_H
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
...
```

should be

```
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
#define PRUEBA_H
....
```

Answer (score 4):

A *very* subtle one, these first two lines are in the wrong order<sup>1</sup>:

```
#define PRUEBA_H
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
// declare everything
#endif
```

What this is doing is defining the symbol then, because it *is* defined, everything between the `#ifndef` and `#endif` is not included.

It needs to be:

```
#ifndef PRUEBA_H
#define PRUEBA_H
```

instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> So obviously your third bullet point of things you checked:

- Checking #define /#ifndef

could have possibly done with a little *more* checking :-)

Comment: Dislexia can be very time consuming... Thank you guys!